# SoftDelete pattern using IDbCommandTreeInterceptor doesn't work when CascadeDelete is disabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I followed [this](https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-TechEd2014/tree/master/FakeEstate.ListingManager/Models/EFHelpers) example to enabled some of the entities on the application to use the SoftDelete pattern.

However, this doesn't work in the following case ([source code here](https://github.com/cchanpromys/EfQuestion)):

1. Cascade Delete is disabled (see [this](https://github.com/cchanpromys/EfQuestion/blob/5ad445667b4f4d5c8dccc0913b8eb54b7216eb3e/EfCreateObj/Context.cs#L22))
2. When a related child record is loaded into the identity table (like [this](https://github.com/cchanpromys/EfQuestion/blob/5ad445667b4f4d5c8dccc0913b8eb54b7216eb3e/EfCreateObj/Tests/SoftDeleteFixture.cs#L57))

In the example, obviously firing an `UPDATE` statement to set (`Status = 1`) should not cause any problem. However, it looks like EF is doing some kind of FK checks before firing the actual SQL statement.

It throws the following without firing an `UPDATE`:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Is there a way to workaround this problem?

Comment: Changing the Room.HouseId property type to Nullable<int> should be a workaround, but you will end-up with SoftDeleted-Houses with no room... and orphaned rooms...
To prevent this, I guess you will have to intercept the UPDATE statements setting Room.HouseId to null, and prevent changing the value. Never tried that... yet...

Comment: @jbl, I agree that would work, but that would mean I have to change the DB which I currently cannot. The problem with adding additional interceptors is that EF actually fires its own validation (to check for `ConceptualNull`) before the interceptor code fires. I need a way to tell it to bypass those checks.